# How to merge two simple JSON arrays together with JQ

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I want to merge to arrays together.

```
$ cat file.json
[1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7,8]
$ # command
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

What should `# command` be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another simple way, using just `add`:

```sh
jq -s 'add' input.json
```

<sup>[[Documentation]](http://%5B1%5D)</sup>

---

- ###### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ktA1qJV23T)
- Local shell example

  ```
  $ cat input.json
  [1,2,3,4]
  [5,6,7,8]
  $
  $ jq -s 'add' input.json
  [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8
  ]
  $
  ```

Answer (score 2):

```
jq -s 'flatten(1)' file.json
```

Explanation:

- [`flatten(1)`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example36) de-nests arrays with depth of 1.
- `-s` runs the command on all the items (ie. both lists) rather than each item independently.

Comment: A little overkill for the problem but +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way

```sh
jq -n '[inputs[]]' file.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4DVGc5Dhp3)

Comment: Same idea; `jq -s '[.[][]]'`

Answer (score 1):

The `c` option prints to one line.
Also if you want to merge the two arrays and keep them sorted you can do this:

```
jq -cn '[inputs[]] | sort' file.json
```

For example, it will still be in order in the case below:

```
$ cat file.json
[1,2,3,5]
[4,6,7,8]
$ jq -cn '[inputs[]] | sort '  file.json
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```